# day difference between dates and check convert the text in date

Tags: solaris, ksh

My intention of writing a shell-script (ksh) is to list all the files in a directory and check the creted date. If the date exceeds 30 days, the files are zipped in another location.

ksh code :

```
--extracts the day and date of the file

ls -al | awk '{print $6$7}'
```

output

```
May23 Jun13 .......
```

Now, when i extract the day and date, i believe it is in text. Now, my requirement is to change the text into date and check the created date whether less than 30 days or greater.

However, i googled out an found some good suggestions but none satisfoes mine(as far as i searched).

Could you please suggest as what is required to do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unix systems don't store the file creation date. Good luck.

Comment: Hi, i believe when i ls i get the modified date >

Comment: Yes, if you do `man find` you'll see "-ctime n File's status was last changed n*24 hours ago." Changed, not Created. That said, for files that have not be had any changes made to them, `-ctime` and `-mtime`  will work. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use ls for this. Use `find`, e.g.

```
find . -type f -ctime +30
```

or similar-type command.

Comment: @coolmego, you should now reward Marc by accepting his answer.